# Angular Template-Driven form reset programmatically

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular10

I'm new to Angular/Typescript and currently using a Template-Driven form in Angular 10. I'm trying to reset the form without submitting it and without clicking a button. I've checked out similar issues but they all rely on submitting the form in order to reset it. I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined
```

Below is my TS file code:

```
@ViewChild('visitorForm', { static: true }) visitorForm: NgForm;

constructor(private myService: MyService)
{
  this.myService.imagePosted.subscribe(
    userDetails => {
      this.userDetails = userDetails;
     this.visitorForm.reset();
    }
  );
}
```

And here is my component.html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(visitorForm)" #visitorForm="ngForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 form-group">
        <input 
        [ngModel]="visitor.firstName"
        required 
        type="text" 
        id="firstName" 
        name="firstName" 
        placeholder="First Name" 
        class="form-control"
        #firstName="ngModel">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I can clear the form on submit or if I use a button with an event binded to it, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to reset the form within the subscribe above. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Move the code to ngAfterViewInit() so the reference to the form exists and then try with resetForm():

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

https://angular.io/guide/forms

Stackblitz demo of template-driven form reset using different methods:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-workbench-template-driven-form

Be careful with the sintax as it is very tricky! :-)

Comment: Thanks for responding Daniel. Unfortunately I've tried resetForm() and I receive pretty much the same error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'resetForm' of undefined`

Comment: I see, the problem is that you're are calling it in the constructor and the reference to the form is not available yet. Move that code to the ngOnInit() and it should work. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Just tried moving it into ngOnInit() but no luck. It's still coming back with the same undefined error.

Comment: Then use hook ngAfterViewInit() to make sure the form has been built and the reference exist. Updated answer.

Comment: Same undefined error when using ngAfterViewInit(). I really thought that one would work! I tried outputting the form using `console.log(this.visitorForm);` and it's verified that it's `undefined`

Comment: Please see this stackblitz I prepared with a demonstration of template-driven forms reset, you can see the form is reset from the template, from an interval and after submit. Be careful with the sintax, is very tricky. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-workbench-template-driven-form

Comment: I can successfully reset the form via onSubmit() because I'm passing the instance of the form, but I'm still unable to do so from within the Subscribe block. I keep getting the same undefined error. I found a "dirty" workaround where I just set each field individually to `null`. It's certainly not my preferred method but it's the only method that will work it seems.

Comment: Remember that the subscription has to be done in the ngAfterViewInit() so that the reference exists and double check the template form sintax. I would recommend you forking and playing with my Stackblitz so you can isolate the problem with a simpler scenario or post a Stackblitz with your complete code so we can give a look. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Daniel! My subscription is still in the ngAfterViewInit(), but I'll fork and do some tinkering!